# Image caption within \newfloat

Tags: floats, captions

I am using the `float` package to create my own floats.  Now I also want to add an image with its own caption inside, but the caption belongs to the outer float.  Is it possible to create something like a `figure` environment inside my float?  I that already but it does not work inside the float.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}

\newfloat{infobox}{tbp}{ext}

\begin{document}

\begin{infobox}
  \begin{framed}
    \blindtext      
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{dummy}
    \caption{Caption for the image}
  \end{framed}
\end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Floating environments defined with `\newfloat` do not respect the position of the `\caption` command but always use the selected float style instead which have a fixed, pre-defined caption position. They behave differently regarding this aspect than `figure` and `table`. (BTW: To make `figure` and `table` behave like environments defined with `\newfloat`, the `float` package offers `\restylefloat`.)

So if you want to have a floating environment which behaves like `figure` and `table` and let you place the `\caption` where you want to, do not use `\newfloat` but `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` (or `\DeclareCaptionType`) offered by the `newfloat` package, or `\DeclareNewTOC` offered by the KOMA-Script document classes.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% "demo" added because we don't have your picture file

\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}% caption added since you use it anyway
\usepackage{framed}

%\newfloat{infobox}{tbp}{ext}
\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=ext]{infobox}
  % \newfloat replaced by \DeclareCaptionType

\begin{document}

\begin{infobox}
  \begin{framed}
    \blindtext      
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{dummy}
    \caption{Caption for the image}
  \end{framed}
\end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I've added the `caption` package since (according your comment) you use it anyway. If you don't use the `caption` package, the straight-ahead way would be loading the `newfloat` package and using `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` instead.

**BUT:** If all `infoboxes` should be framed a different (and IMHO better) approach would be using the `boxed` style of the `float` (or `floatrow`) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{infobox}{tbp}{ext}
\restylefloat*{infobox}
\floatname{infobox}{Infobox}

\begin{document}

\begin{infobox}
  \blindtext      
  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{dummy}
  \caption{Caption for the image}
\end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

(The `\restylefloat*` is necessary so the caption will be placed inside the frame. Without it the caption would always been outside the frame.)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I found out that the subfig package somehow fails with my document (cannot reproduce this in a minimal example unfortunately), so I ended up using your `subcaption` package + `float`, which now works as intended.

Comment: @your edit: Great, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\captionof` from `capt-of` (or `caption`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of} % or \usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}

\newfloat{infobox}{tbp}{ext}

\begin{document}

\begin{infobox}
  \begin{framed}
    \blindtext      
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption for the image}
  \end{framed}
\end{infobox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that it would need some tweaking if used together with `subfig`, which I just discovered, but it should work, I think.

Comment: @quazgar If you use the `subfig` package, you don't need to include the `capt-of` package.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out that in my "real" document, `\captionof` did not stay inside the frame (could not reproduce it in a MWE, though).  Therefore I used the `subcaption` package, which works as intended after a `\DeclareCaptionType{infobox}` statement.