# changing caption name

Tags: captions

I work with both pictures and schematics, and instead of "figure", I want "Picture" or "Schematics" to show up. Thus I use `\renewcommand` as shown below:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Picture}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{my_picture.png}
\caption{This is my picture}
\end{figure}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Schematics}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    code
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is my schematics}
\end{figure}
```

The result of the caption would be:

- Picture 1.1 : This is my picture
- Schematics 1.2 : This is my schematics

meaning that they are enumerated commonly, starting from 1. Is there a way both of them to have individual enumeration, such as

- Picture 1.1 : This is my picture
- Schematics 1.1 : This is my schematics
- Picture 1.2 : This is my picture
- Schematics 1.2 : This is my schematics
- etc ......

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I believe you want to look at the `newfloat` package.

Comment: changing `\figurename` should not change the counting, it should do exactly as you wish.

Comment: You want a new floating environment. Aside from `newfloat`, you can also use package `tocbasic`. This will also give you two separate lists.

Comment: [Using KOMA-Script packages with other classes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218964) Exactly what you want, but you might want to change *Remark* to *Shematic*.

Comment: All remarks were quite useful. Finally I used some code from the question **"Image caption withing \neofolat"** http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115499/image-caption-within-newfloat and works fine.