# How to use accentend characters in newfloat

Tags: floats, captions, environments, unicode, newfloat

I am using `\newfloat` to redefine numbers of Figures, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115499/image-caption-within-newfloat).
I used the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=ext]{Grafico}
\begin{document}
```

And worked. But I would like that the captions of the new floats to be called as Gr**á**fico 1 -
When I try:
`\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=ext]{Gráfico}` I got an error.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how `newfloat` works.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=grf,
  listname={Lista de gráficos},
  name=Gráfico,
]{grafico}

\begin{document}

\listofgrafico

\begin{grafico}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}

\caption{Ejemplo de gráfico}

\end{grafico}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `utf8` because my system is set up for it. You should switch, too.